# How to unit testing spring boot rest controller and exception handler using power mock

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, powermock, powermockito

I am having a simple Spring boot application which contains Employee controller which returns the Employee names if the year passed  is greater than 2014 and if the it is not less than 2014 then I am throwing a custom exception and handling it in Exception Handler.
 I want to unit test the exception flow using powermock but I am not sure how to do it. I have gone through some links but unable to understand.

Currently I am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required.

EmployeeController.java

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController{

    @GetMapping(value = "/employee/{joiningYear}",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<String> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable int joiningYear) throws YearViolationException {

        if(joiningYear < 2014){
            throw new YearViolationException("year should not be less than 2014");
        }else{

            // send all employee's names joined in that year 
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

ExceptionHandler

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {


    @ExceptionHandler(value = { YearViolationException.class })
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ApiErrorResponse yearConstraintViolationExceptio(YearViolationException ex) {

        return new ApiErrorResponse(400, 5001, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

CustomException

```
public class YearViolationException extends Exception {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public YearViolationException(String message) {

        super(message);
    }

}
```

Junit to unit test exception handler

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class ExceptionControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMVC;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        mockMVC = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(applicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testhandleBanNotNumericException() throws Exception {

        mockMVC.perform(get("/employee/2010").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
        .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace; to point out in which line that error happens. Beyond that: it is not clear what you are doing here. You see, the point of a unit test would be to **invoke** a method within some "class under test"; to then assert on outputs; or verify a mock object used during that operation. Your code **only** creates a Mock object; and specifies calls on that. I don't see where you call your production code?! (maybe that is because I am not familiar with these frameworks, but still something seems to be missing). Beyond that: you dont need PowerMock here.

Comment: You only need PowerMock when you want to mock **static** methods or calls to `new` . If you dont have that scenario (and you should **avoid** having that scenario!) ... then you dont need to go for PowerMock. You could be using simple Mockito instead.

Comment: @GhostCat I have created dummy code as I cannot post actual project code. There is no logic as u pointed out which is correct. Here I created replica of project code where I have to write unit test using powermock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by others, you don't need mockMVC at all. If you want to test REST endpoints, what you need is TestRestTemplate.
Runwith SpringRunner.class is important as well as the WebEnvironment setup.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RestServiceApplicationTests {

    private String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8090";

    private String endpointToThrowException = "/employee/2010";

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Test(expected = YearViolationException.class)
    public void testhandleBanNotNumericException() {
        testRestTemplate.getForObject(baseUrl + endpointToThrowException, String.class);
}
```

Comment: This code seems to tell Spring to use a random port: webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, but runs the @Test against a hard coded url with port 8090. How can that work? I think with RANDOM_PORT we should use:     AT LocalServerPort
    private int port;

Comment: Is this Unit or Integration test (@SpringBootTest) ? In my opinion this is not a unit test

Comment: You are correct, since we are configuring an environment and a context as well, this is more like an  integration test. The question itself is flawed by design, since controller testing indicates an integration test not a unit test.

Answer (score -1):

From how your setup looks, you don't need to use Mocks at all. It seem's like you want to load the complete application context and use mockMVC to send requests against your rest controller. This is actually and integrationtest!

Now, unfortunately we use Spring Boot 1.3 here, so I'm not sure if the combination of `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest` in fact loads the Application context. Check your logs and see if it does and if not, try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
```

If, on the other hand you want to make a simple unit test, then you don't need to load the application context. Instead you can just use regular Mockito with `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` in conjuntion with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and call the method you want to test directly as you would any other method under test.

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi I want to write the unit test for the exception handler i.e when a exception is thrown from the rest controller then exception handler handles it correctly.

Comment: Ah my bad for not reading thourougly. Can you confirm your application context successfully loads?

Comment: If I use SpringBootTest , RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and WebAppConfiguration then WebApplicationContext loads but when I am using RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) , WebAppConfiguration and SpringBootTest I am getting the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required as I am doing autowiring

Comment: Since you can only use one RunWith you have to use SpringRunner. What do you need PowerMockRunner for? From Mockito I know that you can achieve the same that MockitoJUnitRunner does with a method call in @Before (`MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`.