# How to start spring boot application for the sake of integration testing

Tags: java, spring

I am wondering. How do you start a springboot application from a unit test? I am working on building an integration test suite, and I want to start the application in the test so the integration tests can run. It seems like there should be a pretty straight forward way to do this, but I don't see how to do it.

Comment: Do you use Maven?

Comment: Im using gradle. I dont just want to execute all the tests. I want to startup the actual application and then run test against it.

Comment: What do you mean executed right after build? You mean once the appliaction is deployed? Is starting the application in the build server unusual, or what is unusual?

Comment: This guy actually helped me... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582692/spring-boot-application-is-starting-up-from-a-junit-test-but-unable-to-access-th